# How to remove skull, which obscures the vision?

Tags: overwatch

Each time you kill someone a skull appears, that obscures your vision for a second. How to avoid it and make the targets behind it visible?
Anything would be good, for example, remove the skull, make it more transparent, make it different color (so at least I can see the outlines of the enemy).

[image]

Comment: Is this really a big deal? The skull shows for a quarter of a second at most, and verifies that the target is dead. In the screenshot you provided, it looks like that person is already been killed, the red outline just hasn't been removed yet.

Comment: @MageXy, first of all, why is it important if it is big deal or not? I just want it to be removed. Second, it is not a quarter of a second, it is longer than mccree shoot cool-down (0.5 sec). The image illustrates how after killing one enemy (killed enemies disappear immediately) you can hardly find a head of another enemy.

Comment: If you can find another opponents head in that timeframe, what's the issue? It obviously doesn't interfere.

Comment: @Frank, erm? "Can hardly find = can't find". You can remember its position, but you can't see it at the time when your weapon is ready to shoot, so you must to shoot blindly.

Comment: I fail to see where the intent of question matters, or whether it's a "big deal" or not. The question was asked, an answer was given, let's move on with our days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to change the UI in that way currently and no planned feature to do so. Right now the only way you possibly could have the skull not show up is by turning off the entire UI with Alt+Z but this would cause far more problems by having literally no HUD.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to do so.